# TSQL query help structuring results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, grouping

I have a table with the following columns:

```
timestamp | value | desc
```

example of the data:

```
2014-01-27 10:00:00.000 | 100 | 101
2014-01-27 10:00:00.000 | 105 | 101
2014-01-27 11:00:00.000 | 160 | 101
2014-01-27 12:00:00.000 | 200 | 101
...
...
2014-01-28 10:00:00.000 | 226 | 101
2014-01-28 10:00:00.000 | 325 | 101
2014-01-28 11:00:00.000 | 145 | 101
```

what I would like to obtain is a grouping by the hour part but without merging the period interval.
So that the result will be like this (in the select I will pass a date interval and a condition on the description like desc = '101':

Structure:

```
hour | count
```

Data:

```
10 | 2    (referring to the 20140127)
11 | 1    (referring to the 20140127)
12 | 1    (referring to the 20140127)
...
...
10 | 2    (referring to the 20140128)
11 | 1    (referring to the 20140128)
```

I thought about using a cursor but I was wondering if it is possible to achieve this result without it.

I'm using **SQL server 2012 SP1**.

Thanks for your attention.

Bye,
F.

Comment: In Oracle, I'd do `SELECT to_char(timestamp, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24'), count(*) FROM myTable GROUP BY to_char(timestamp, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24')`. Just find a SQL Server equivalent for `to_char(timestamp, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24')`.

Comment: Or also in Oracle, I always use `Select Extract (hour from timestamp), count(*) from myTable GROUP BY Extract (hour from timestamp)`

Comment: In SQL Server you can use GROUP BY DATEPART( hh, timestamp )

Comment: Giacomo with GROUP BY DATEPART( hh, timestamp ) it will merge the date parts of all the period so that 10:00 of the 20140127 will be merged with 10:00 of the 20140128 counting a total of 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
SELECT Count(*)                  AS [Count], 
       Datepart(hour, timestamp) AS [Hour] 
FROM   yourtable 
GROUP  BY CONVERT(DATE, timestamp), 
          Datepart(hour, timestamp) 
ORDER  BY CONVERT(DATE, timestamp)
```

Comment: so this works like a charm both of the answers, the missing part was the group by on the entire date to preserve the period.
Thank you very much, I will give the answer to the first poster but both of them were valid.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this. This should work

```
SELECT DATEPART(hh,timestamp), COUNT(*) 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY 
DATEPART(hh,timestamp),
DATETIMEFROMPARTS (YEAR(timestamp),MONTH(timestamp),DAY(timestamp),0,0,0,0,0),
desc HAVING desc ='yourvalue'
```

Comment: so this works like a charm both of the answers, the missing part was the group by on the entire date to preserve the period.
Thank you very much, I will give the answer to the first poster but both of them were valid.

Comment: i need 15 reputation :( i will do when i reach it, sorry i'm new to this community